# How to convert Variant Safe Array into Char using C++ win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, adsi

Hai i want to convert the `&var` values into char array.
how can i achieve this?
i am using C++ Win32 API. 
   [image: Safe Array to Char]

Open image in another tab,you will get clear View.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ATL::CComSafeArray. Assume you have a pointer to safe array in variable pSa,

```
CComSafeArray<BSTR> array;
array.Attach(pSa);

for(int i=0; i< array.GetCount(); ++i)
{
  std::wcout << (const wchar_t*) array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to use just win32,

```
SafeArrayLock(pSa);
LONG uBound = -1, lBound = 0;
SafeArrayUBound(pSa,1,uBound);
SafeArrayUBound(pSa,1,lBound);
int nCount = uBound - lBound + 1;
for(int i = 0; i<nCount; ++i)
{
 std::wcout << ((BSTR*)(pSa->pvData))[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Remember to call Detach if you don't want CComSafeArray to take ownership of the safe array object pointed to by pSa.

Comment: @ Nanda: How to get `CComSafeArray`,`array.GetCount()` keywords in C++ Win32 API.

Comment: If you do not want to use ATL here is are the API you have to call in order SafeArrayLock(psa), SafeArrayGetUBound, SafeArrayGetLBound (to know the size) and then for (i = 0 : count) ((BSTR)(psa->pvData))[i].

Comment: @ Nanda:i cant get `(pSa->pvData))[i] ` `->pvData` properties after variables->...what is trhe problem?

Comment: pSa should be of type SAFEARRAY. I am not sure what is that you are finding difficulty with.

Comment: @ Nanda :kindly check my image & tell me.var defined as `VARIANT     var;`.And ur code gives `var cannot convert variant to SAFEARRARY` in SafeArrayLock(var);

Comment: VARIANT is unified structure to hold any one of the various different types like int, char, string, array (anything including variant themselves), it is sort of a blatant polymorphism. If your variant object is holding an array then you should use the parray member of the variant object where ever you need to use the safearray object.